# Apex Test Code Coverage Issue for Aggregate Functions

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests

I have 2 objects Order and Shipment__c. For each Order we can have Multiple shipments and I'm trying to update the Order with MAX(ship Date) from all related shipment records. The trigger and helper class is working as expected but my test class assertion is failing and also the aggregate function is not being covered.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger ShipmentTrigger on Shipment__c (after delete, after insert, after update, after undelete) {
    Map<Id,order> updateMap =new Map<Id,Order>(); 
    Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();
    private static Id RecordTypeId = class.retrieveRecordTypeId('Direct_Shipment', 'Shipment__c');

    if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            for(Shipment__c pod : Trigger.old) {
                orderIds.add(pod.Order__c);
            }          
    } else if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUnDelete){
        for(Shipment__c pod : Trigger.new) {
            if( pod.RecordTypeId != RecordTypeId){
            orderIds.add(pod.Order__c);
        }
    }
 }
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        Shipment__c oldpod;
        for(Shipment__c po : Trigger.new) {
            oldpod = Trigger.oldMap.get(po.Id);
            if( po.RecordTypeId != RecordTypeId && po.Ship_Date__c != oldpod.Ship_Date__c){
                orderIds.add(po.Order__c);
            }
        }
    }
    if(orderIds!=null && orderIds.size()>0) {
         try{
            OrderTriggerHandler.updateShipDateonOrder(orderIds,updateOrderMap);
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            // :: TO DO
         }
    }
```

**Handler:**

```
public with sharing class OrderTriggerHandler {
    public static void updateShipDateonOrder(set<Id> orderIds, Map<Id,Order> updateOrderMap){

       List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [select Order__c, MAX(Ship_Date__c) maxDate from Shipment__c where Order__c IN : orderIds AND Status__c IN ('Confirmed','Received','Partially Received') group by Order__c]; 
           if(AggregateResultList != null && AggregateResultList.size() > 0){ 
               for(AggregateResult aggr:AggregateResultList){             
                      Order od = new Order(); 
                      od.Ship_Date__c = (date)aggr.get('maxDate'); 
                      od.Id = (id)aggr.get('Order__c'); 
                      updateOrderMap.put(od.Id, od); 
                  } 
              } 
           update updateMap.values();      
         }
      }
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest static void testupdateshipdate() {
     Map<Id,Order> updateMap =new Map<Id,Order>(); 
     Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();
     List<Shipment__c> polist = new List<Shipment__c>();               

     Order o = [Select Id, Name, Ship_Date__c, Status from 
                Order where accountId =: well.Id LIMIT 1];

     Shipment__c PO1 = new Shipment__c(Order__c = o.Id, 
     Status__c='Confirmed', Estimated_Ship_Date__c = System.Today());
     insert PO1;

     Shipment__c PO2 = new Shipment__c(Order__c = o.Id, Status__c = 
     'Received', Estimated_Ship_Date__c=System.Today()+100);
     insert PO2;

     Shipment__c PO3 = new Shipment__c(Order__c = o.Id, Status__c = 
     'Partially Received', Estimated_Ship_Date__c=System.Today()+200);
     insert PO3;

     test.starttest();
     polist = [Select Ship_Date__c,Order__c,Status__c from Shipment__c 
     where Order__c =:o.id];
        for(Shipment__c po: polist){
         orderIds.add(po.Order__c);
        }
        List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [select Order__c, MAX(Ship_Date__c) maxDate from Shipment__c where Order__c IN : orderIds AND Status__c IN ('Confirmed','Received','Partially Received') group by Order__c];
        System.debug('@@@@@'+ AggregateResultList);
           if(AggregateResultList != null && AggregateResultList.size() > 0){ 
               for(AggregateResult aggr:AggregateResultList){             
                      Order od = new Order(); 
                      od.Ship_Date__c = (date)aggr.get('maxDate'); 
                      od.Id = (id)aggr.get('Order__c'); 
                      updateOrderMap.put(od.Id, od); 
            } 
         } 
       update updateMap.values();
       system.assertequals(o.Ship_Date__c, PO3.Ship_Date__c);             
       test.stoptest();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've performed an `update` DML on `Order` in your test class, but your trigger is on `Shipment__c`. Unless you also have a trigger on `Order`, nothing whatsoever is going to happen.

Also, your test class doesn't declare `updateOrderMap`, and your handler doesn't declare `updateMap`, so I'm not clear on whether this is uncompiled code or if you changed it for your post for some reason.

```
   update updateOrderMap.values();
   system.assertequals(o.Estimated_Ship_Date__c, PO3.Estimated_Ship_Date__c);
```

You do not re-query these fields (both called `Estimated_Ship_Date__c`) from the records that you expect to be updated by your trigger. The field contents of your objects are *not* updated automatically, except the population of the `Id` field upon insert. You need to perform at least one SOQL query to update the object whose values are expected to have changed before you perform the assertion.

It's not clear what coverage you are trying to add. Broadly, you need to make sure that your generated test data will result in execution of that code path in test context.

Comment: Hi David, I made edits to code, also made a query to get the order ship value and compared with PO3, he assertion is success but still the aggregate function is not being covered

Comment: I have no idea which line (s) you are referring to